# jQuery autocomplete - request doesn't get sent

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, firebug, jquery-autocomplete

I'm trying to have jQuery autocomplete point to a PHP file (which gathers data from MySQL).

First I tried it with sample data from a Javascript array and it worked:

```
var tags = ["a", "ab", "abc", "abcd", "adbce"];
      $("input#name").autocomplete({
        position: {
          offset: "0 -10px",
        },
        source: tags
      });
```

But when I point to a file which returns data in JSON format (following the official documentation) it doesn't work. I thought it was a problem in the PHP, but when I checked firebug it turned out the request is never being sent in the first place

This is the code I'm using:

```
$("input#name").autocomplete({
        position: {
          offset: "0 -10px",
        },
        source: "http://absolutepathtofile/autosuggest.php"
      });
```

And the screenshot from firebug (homepage.js is the file which contains the autocomplete code above):

[image: firebug Net/JS list of sent requests]

I can provide the PHP code but I don't think it really matters since the problem should be in Javascript - let's say I am using this test code in autosuggest.php:

```
$array[0]="test";
$array[1]="test1";

echo json_encode($array);
```

Anyone know what's wrong here?

Comment: is `http://absolutepathtofile/autosuggest.php` from the same domain and protocol as the current page?

Comment: Yes, it's on the same domain, I used the absolute path to make sure I wasn't pointing to the wrong thing.

Comment: The same protocol aswell? You're actually more sure about using the correct site when using relative urls. Also, your `net` tab in the screenshot is pointing to `JS` requests, it should point to `XHR` requests.

Comment: I don't know, how do I check if it's the same protocol? I've never had this problem before. I tried a relative path, same outcome.

Comment: What format is the array in when it reaches the client?  Can you use Fiddler extract the actual value?

Comment: The protocol is the `http` part, if your current page uses `https` it cannot be reached like this.

Comment: OK, I got it to work. My premise was all wrong - as red-X pointed out, I was looking at the JS tab instead of the XHR tab - the request was being sent, but the response wasn't, and that got fixed when I used a relative path. It works now. Red, if you want to post your comments as an answer I'll gladly accept it. Thanks.

Comment: Posted it, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `net` tab in the screenshot is pointing to `JS` requests, it should point to `XHR` requests.